# pidof in cron not finding process?

Tags: bash, cron

I'd like to restart my daemon if it's not running (crashed etc). inittab is not applicable for various reasons. This snippet works fine in bash but not from cron as it keeps starting multiple processes:

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash if [ ! $(pidof vzlogger) ]; then sudo vzlogger -d; fi;
```

Is the subshell "eating" the exit code of `pidof`? The alternative

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash if [ -z "$(pidof vzlogger)" ]; then sudo vzlogger -d; fi;
```

has the same problem- multiple processes?

Comment: As outlined in the answer, "works fine in bash" is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to run Bash commands is not `bash commands` but `bash -c 'commands'`.

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash -c 'pidof vzlogger >/dev/null || sudo vzlogger -d'
```

Of course, the `/1` is redundant, and you don't need Bash for any of this.

```
* * * * * pidof vzlogger >/dev/null || sudo vzlogger -d
```

The `if test` wasn't incorrect per se, but it can very often be avoided.  So, for example, `pidof` fortunately returns error if it did not find a PID, and success otherwise; so you can use the shortcut syntax.  (Most properly maintained Unix tools have this feature.)  Because the PID is no longer captured in a (superfluous) process substitution, we redirect the output from `pidof` to `/dev/null` (because otherwise you will receive email from the cron daemon every time it succeeds and generates output).

`/bin/bash if` will search for a file named `if` in the current directory (which for a cron job is your home directory), and attempt to execute it as a Bash script.

You should have received an email from the cron daemon with an error message:

```
bash: if: No such file or directory
```